# Bokeh line 'disappearing' when using hover_line_alpha

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm using the Bokeh package to plot a line chart.

***I want a given line to bolden (alpha to increase) when I hover over it.
I added a hover tool and then added "hover_line_alpha = 0.6" in my line chart.***

However when I hover over points on a given line, the line disappears altogether!

Can you help me fix this?

Code below so you can see my logic.

Thanks,
Ross

```
# Code in Question
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show, output_file
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool

output_notebook()

# set out axes
x = 'time_rnd'
y = 'count'

# set colour palette
col_brew = ['#8dd3c7','#ffffb3','#bebada','#fb8072','#80b1d3','#fdb462','#b3de69','#fccde5','#d9d9d9','#bc80bd','#ccebc5','#ffed6f']

# map out figure
plot = figure(tools='box_select, lasso_select, save' ,x_axis_type='datetime')

# add HoverTool
hover_info = [('time', '@hover_time'),
          ('word', '@word'),
          ('count', '@count')]
hover = HoverTool(names=['use'],tooltips=hover_info,
              mode='mouse',
              show_arrow=True
             )
plot.add_tools(hover)


### FOR LOOP OF PLOT [THIS IS WHERE THE ISSUE MANIFESTS]

for i in top_wds_test:

  df_eng_word = df_eng_timeline[df_eng_timeline['word']==i]

  source = ColumnDataSource(df_eng_word)

  plot.line(x, y, line_width = 3, 
        line_alpha = 0.1, line_color=col_brew[top_wds.index(i)], 
        hover_line_alpha = 0.6,
        #hover_line_color = 'black',
        #hover_line_color = col_brew[top_wds.index(i)], 
        source = source, legend=i, name = 'use'
       )

  plot.circle(x, y, fill_color='white', size=5, 
          selection_color='green',
          nonselection_fill_color='grey',nonselection_fill_alpha=0.4, 
          hover_color='red',
          source = source, name = 'use')

# add legend
plot.legend.location = "top_left"
plot.legend.label_text_font_style = 'bold'

# materialize the plot
show(plot)
```

Comment: Is the above code correct? It doesn't match your description. This code has a hover alpha of 0.1 (nearly invisible), not 0.6 as stated above.

Comment: Apologies I was tinkering with the code to see if I could remedy it. You're right it should be as follows: "line_alpha = 0.1, line_color=col_brew[top_wds.index(i)], 
            hover_line_alpha = 0.6," --- amended code above. However the issue still occurs on my side.

Comment: Can you add some minimal fake data so the example code is complete and can be run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be an issue when the renderers share a data source. However, this works (with Bokeh >= `0.13.0`) if you let Bokeh create a new separate source for each glyph:

```
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show

p = figure(tools="hover", tooltips="$name: @$name")

data=dict(x=[1,2,3], y1=[2,6,5], y2=[6,2,3])

p.line('x', 'y1', color="navy", line_width=3, source=data,
       alpha=0.1, hover_color="navy", hover_alpha=0.6, name="y1")

p.line('x', 'y2',color="firebrick", line_width=3, source=data,
       alpha=0.1, hover_color="firebrick", hover_alpha=0.6, name="y2")

show(p)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks guys! I agree it has something to do with the fact I'm sharing the source across both circle and line plots. To remedy the situation I just removed the circle plot and now the hover tooltip works as planned.

Comment: If you'd like to keep the circle, you can restrict the hover to to just the line glyphs by using the `renderers` property on the tool to explicitly list just the renderers you care about.